# How to debug build faild in ios for nativescript apps?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I just run `tns run ios --emulator` and I get this:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/proj/projfront/App/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m:87:34: error: no known class method for selector
      'labelColor'
       _contentColor = [[UIColor labelColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f];
                                 ^~~~
/Users/me/Desktop/proj/projfront/App/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m:378:101: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge'
                activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleLarge];
                                                                                                    ^
/Users/me/Desktop/proj/projfront/App/platforms/ios/Pods/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.m:1065:32: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'UIBlurEffectStyleSystemThickMaterial'
            _blurEffectStyle = UIBlurEffectStyleSystemThickMaterial;
                               ^
3 errors generated.
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
* BUILD FAILED *

Unable to apply changes on device: 96EBA70E-38D5-4C6A-B30B-21BECF697C9C. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
```

I have no idea how to debug this. It builds just fine on Android.
**Here is my package.json:**

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "templateVersion": "v2",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/theme": "^2.2.1",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^1.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "^2.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "nativescript-exoplayer": "^4.0.2",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "^4.0.3",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.3.3",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "^6.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wild guess - things like UIBlurEffectStyleSystemThickMaterial are only available on the very latest iOS, and will fail if your target is lower than that ?

Comment: Can you confirm your {N} run time version and the plugin name you are using?

Comment: ✔ Component nativescript has 6.3.3 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.3.2 version and is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labelColor` is a new property introduced with iOS 13. You need XCode 11 to build for iOS 13.x and above. So that said, one of the plugins is brining a pod called MBProgressHUD. That pod is using the newest iOS API. But your build is failing most likely because it is built with XCode 10.x or lower version. To resolve the issue try building with XCode 11, and with latest `tns-ios` (6.3.x and above) + latest `tns-core-modules`.

Comment: So if I stick with this plugin people with IOS version below 13 won't be able to use my app?

Comment: how can I figure which plugin is using it?

Comment: Just search for the MBProgressHUD -   `@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator`

Comment: Could you please also answer my first comment?

Comment: I have the same issue but i am using sidekick cloud build and i have xcode 11. What can i do?

Comment: Is there any possiblty to fix this issue without changing the code. I use nativescript 3.0